# ImportError: cannot import name 'HalvingGridSearchCV' from 'sklearn.model_selection'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

I am running scikit-learn 0.24.2 on the intelpython3_full conda distribution.
I am trying to run:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import HalvingGridSearchCV
```

and get the following error:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'HalvingGridSearchCV' from 'sklearn.model_selection'
```

I am trying to run it from jupyter notebook.

Already tried reinstalling scikit-learn:

```py
conda uninstall scikit-learn
conda install scikit-learn -c intel
```

Also tried:

```py
-c conda-forge
```

Always get this error. Other imports with sklearn, for instance GridSearchCV work.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This must be run first:

```py
from sklearn.experimental import enable_halving_search_cv
```

and then this:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import HalvingGridSearchCV
```